# Polymorphism with copy constructor

Tags: c++, polymorphism, copy-constructor

Here is the code I use. I'd like to know if what I did is correct and safe. Normally it compiles and the tests I did are successful. But as it is the first time that I use `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast`, I'd like to be sure that I didn't miss anything.

Can you please check :

- that I don't forget to delete any pointer (I don't really understand what my clone method does...)
- if I use correctly `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast`
- that there is not a more efficient of doing it

But my main concern is that I correctly implement the `clone() method`

Thanks a lot!!!

### Edit

Thanks to some answer I realized that I should redesign my code. So I could get rid of this piece of code...

the .hpp file:

```
#include <vector>

/*!Base class that will never be instantiate. It provides a way to create
 * GenericData with defferent type. */
class Data{
    public:
        /*!Constructor*/
        Data(std::string name):name_(name){}
        /*!Destructor, must be virtual*/
        virtual ~Data(){};

        /*!Method that allows a copy of the derived class*/
        virtual Data* clone() const = 0;

    protected:
        std::string name_;//!< Name of the (Generic)Data 

};

/*!Derived class that can contain any one value of any type and of name name_*/
template<typename Type>
class GenericData : public Data{
    public:
        /*!Constructor*/
        GenericData(std::string name, Type t): Data(name), t_(t){}
        /*!Destructor*/
        ~GenericData(){};

        /*!Method that implements*/
        GenericData<Type>* clone() const { return new GenericData<Type>(static_cast<GenericData<Type> const&>(*this) );}

        /*!Returns the value of the data*/
        Type const& get_val() const {return t_;}

    private:
        Type t_;//!< Value of the GenericData
};

/*!Contains a vector of Data*, can store diffrent GenericData*/
class Container{
    public:
        Container(){};
        Container(Container const& c){ 
            for(unsigned int i(0);i<c.data_.size();i++){
                data_.push_back((c.data_[i])->clone());
            }
        }
        ~Container(){
            for(unsigned int i(0);i<data_.size();i++){
                delete data_[i];
                data_[i] = NULL;
            }
        }

        /*!Add one GenericData<Type> of value t and named name*/
        template<typename Type>
            void set(std::string name, Type const& t){data_.push_back(new GenericData<Type>(name,t));}

        /*!Returns the value GenericData<Type>::t_ named name*/
        template<typename Type>
            Type get(std::string name) const;

    private:
        std::vector<Data*> data_;
};

template<typename Type>
void Container::set(std::string name, Type const& t){
    data_.push_back(new GenericData<Type>(name,t));
}

template<typename Type>
Type Container::get(std::string name) const {
    for(unsigned int i(0);i<data_.size();i++){
        if(data_[i]->get_name()==name){
            return dynamic_cast< GenericData<Type> *>(data_[i])->get_val();
        }
    }
    std::cerr<<"Container : get(string name) : no data with name "<<name<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the cast in the `clone()` method. And `clone()` should return `Data*`. The inheritance will do the right thing. (unless its away to late to be reading source for me).

Comment: @WhozCraig In most cases, I'd have `clone()` return `Data*` too, but C++ does support covariant returns, so having it return a pointer to the derived class is legal.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is, but in doing so, having a raw `Data *p` and invoking `p->clone()` will *work* ?? (i.e. invoke the proper derived-clone that differs only in return-type?) If so, I need to go get my standard and start reading how that wires up (as if it wasn't obvious I wouldn't code this as-presented to begin with). IF you know the covariant section of the standard off the cuff, kindly refer me, no biggie if you don't, i'll hunt it down anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes.  That's what covariant return means.  In C++11,
it's in §10.3/7 (but it's been present since C++98).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GenericData<Type>* clone() const{
    return new GenericData<Type>(static_cast<GenericData<Type> const&>(*this) );
}
```

Here you don't need to use `static_cast` because type of `*this` is already `const GenericData<Type>&`.

================================================

```
    if(data_[i]->get_name()==name){
        return dynamic_cast< GenericData<Type> *>(data_[i])->get_val();
    }
```

Here you need to check whether `dynamic_cast` returns null pointer. null pointer will be returned if data_[i] is not of type `GenericData<Type>*` (or if it's not a pointer to some type derived from `GenericData<Type>`)

=============================================
You also need to define `Container::operator=`. If you don't define it the compiler will generate it for you and `vector<Data*>` can be improperly copied.

=============================================

Also my advice is to use `std::shared_ptr<Data>` (of `boost::shared_ptr<Data>` if you use C++98) or `std::unique_ptr<>` instead of `Data*` to avoid manual object deletion and related potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding that you are re-implementing `std::map` in a terrible way (do you really want to allow storing `GenericData<string>` and `GenericData<float>` in the same container?), your `clone` method should not even compile because you are invoking `GenericData<T>`'s copy constructor without having defined one. How about this simple and readable alternative:

```
Data* clone() const {
    return new GenericData<Type>(name_, t_);
}
```

Comment: The default copy-ctor is neither `delete`ed nor `private`-ized. It should compile (assuming all the other errors like redecl of `set`, etc.are fixed). Its the data access that is somewhat puzzling to me. (as in, i fail to see the point).

Comment: "never heard of std::map" — you should learn about it before you write your next line of code. Then *maybe* learn about `boost::any` (but don't base your *application* design on it!)

Comment: @n.m. I completely changed my application design. Because of your comment and LumpN's one "do you really want to allow storing GenericData<string> and GenericData<float> in the same container?". So I don't need my `Container` class anymore...